# In a right angled triangle prove this result

Tags: geometry

In a right angled triangle, $ABC$,if $\angle C=90^{\circ}$, and $CD\perp AB$, then show that $\frac{1}{CD^2}=\frac{1}{AC^2}+\frac{1}{BC^2}$

[image]

We have $AB^2=AC^2+BC^2$,
$AC^2=AD^2+CD^2$ and $BC^2=CD^2+BD^2$. But how can I show required result?

Comment: Are you assuming that $AC = BC$? That's what the diagram implies.

Comment: Are there any other relations between the lengths? Can you see anything similar in the three triangles you have? (I assume you drew $AC=BC$ by accident.)

Answer (score 3):

The area of the triangle can be expressed in two ways: $\displaystyle \frac{|AC| |BC|}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{|AB| |CD|}{2}$. Thus, they must be equal:

$$\frac{|AC| |BC|}{2}=\frac{|AB| |CD|}{2}$$

Multiplying throughout by $2$ and squaring,

$$|AC|^2 |BC|^2 = |AB|^2 |CD|^2$$

$$|AC|^2 |BC|^2 = (|AC|^2 + |BC|^2) \cdot |CD|^2$$

$$\frac{1}{|CD|^2} = \frac{|AC|^2 + |BC|^2}{|AC|^2 |BC|^2}$$

$$\therefore \frac{1}{|CD|^2} = \frac{1}{|AC|^2} + \frac{1}{|BC|^2}$$

as required.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I corrected some errors and tidied up the Latex a bit.

Answer (score 0):

TRY TO PROVE AB*CD=AC*CB

THEN square it use  AB^2=AC^2+BC^2

To prove AB * CD=AC * CB

Equate the areas of triangle in terms of AC and CB  and the other one in AB and CD

1/2 AC * CB=1/2 CD * AB